# Django user login form user is none

Tags: python, html, django, forms, authentication

I'm having some trouble logging in users. I have the following views and template:

views.py

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponseRedirect('disabled account')

        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/invalid')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login_page.html', {})
```

login_page.html

```
{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="error"> sorry, thats not a valid username or password</p>
    {% endif %}

<form action="/login/" method="post"> 
    <label for="username">User name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password" value="" id="password">

    <input type="submit" value="login" />

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

My problem is, whenever i hit submit in the login form, no matter what the values are, the page is redirected to the /invald/ url. I have a user set up using the admin function but i still keep getting this error. Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Do i need a forms.py file with anything in it?

Updated views:

```
def login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
         username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
         password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
         user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

         if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('loggedin.html')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account deleted or disabled")


    return render(request, "login_page.html", {'form': form})
```

updated form:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
    password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
    if username and password:
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if not user:
            raise forms.ValidationError("User does not exist.")
        if not user.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError("User is no longer active.")
    return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

updated login_page.html

```
{% block content %}

    {% if form.errors %}
        <p class="error"> sorry, thats not a valid username or password</p>
    {% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post"> 
    {{  form  }}
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

urls:

```
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^invalid/', views.invalid_login, name='invalid_login'),
    url(r'^loggedin/', views.loggedin, name='loggedin'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
```

Comment: The user entry does exist and I am entering the details in correctly, that's what has me stumped.

Comment: Try to use provided by django `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm). Then you could get error description.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe your register code is wrong.
We should use `set_password`

```
def register(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    reg = User()
    reg.username = request.POST['register_username']
    reg.set_password(request.POST['register_password']) #like this line
    reg.save()
```

not reg.password=request.POST['register_password']

Comment: This solved my problem! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make a forms.py file and in here make a class like so:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout, get_user_model

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        password = self.cleaned_data.get("password")
        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User does not exist.")
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError("User is no longer active.")
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then in your views import Login form. Create a view as such:

```
def my_login_view(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
        password = form.cleaned_data["password"]
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('someurl')
            else:
                return redirect('someotherurl')
    return render(request, "your_template_to_process_this_view", {'form': form})
```

In your html template you can call the form using the convention below. For this shortcut to the url to work you need an app_name = "yourappname" at the top of your url file.

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'yourappname:name_given_to_url_in_urls_file' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
<input type="submit" class="btn-success" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm getting a name error "name 'LoginForm' is not defined"

Comment: you need to import it in your views file: from .forms import LoginForm and also make sure you have other required imports in the views file.

Comment: Fixed that, it works now except im back to the first problem - submitting the user data in the form just returns a refreshed login page.

Comment: I had the same problem as you before. It is processing everything but being redirected improperly. The view function my_login_view, you need to create a url for this such as url(r'^login/$', views.my_login_view, name='login'), In the action of the form you call name given to the url which is login in this case. Then you need to create the page it needs to send the user to after login in. You replace 'someurl' with this url to go to the account, or homepage, etc. By the way if this worked, can you give it an up or an accept so other users can use it. Thank you.

Comment: I have that, so I dont think it's the problem (url(r'^login/', views.login, name='login')

Comment: what are you redirecting the user to after the login process? can you post your new code? also check in the terminal to see if you get something like this [01/Sep/2016 11:57:35] "POST /app/login/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 after submitting the form and then this [01/Sep/2016 11:57:35] "GET /app/account HTTP/1.1" 301 0

Comment: I've edited the post with updated code. And yeah when I submit the form the console shows [02/sep/2016 02:30:36] "POST /login/ HTTP/1.1 200 425